# XamlParseException Error Occured in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created PRISM WPF Application. It has two Modules

1. Wpf application, BootStapper, Shell

   2. Class Library, Contains *.resx files.

Here, i have created UserControl.xaml in WPF application and loaded *.resx file like below,

```
xmlns:ResxFile="clr-namespace:Books.Resources.English;assembly=Books.Resources"
 <cb:BaseView.Resources>
        <ResxFile:ScreenFieldNames x:Key="ScreenFieldNames"/>
    </cb:BaseView.Resources>


<TextBlock Text="{Binding AddField, Source={StaticResource ScreenFieldNames}, FallbackValue='Add Field'}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

But i am getting following error

> An exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '62' and line position '20'.

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to add it as a `Resource`. You can access it directly since you have defined the namespace.

```
xmlns:ResxFile="clr-namespace:Books.Resources.English;assembly=Books.Resources"

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static ResxFile:ScreenFieldNames.AddField}"/>
```

Comment: I tried this as well.. Same error is popping out. Is there any other problem?

Comment: make sure the AccessModifier of the resx is set to Public